# How to share a structure with pointers between two unrelated processes with shared memory in C?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, posix, shared-memory

I have a structure which looks like:

```
typedef struct shared_data_t
{
    char *key;
    char *message;
}shared_data;
```

I need to share this structure with another unrelated process. I am using POSIX shared memory with shm_open()/mmap() to achieve this. However, my target process is not getting the shared data and its dieing with SIGSEGV, which is obvious. It will be great if someone help me on this, specially what happens while sharing pointers between two processes with shared memory (with shm_open and mmap).

For a structure like,

```
typedef struct shared_data_t
{
    char key[8];
    char message[32];
}shared_data;
```

it works all fine!

Comment: That's works fine! You just forget that this pointers point outside the shared memory, so another process can't get data. But you can allocate "key" and "message" in shared memory too. Or really make a certain structure without pointers!

Comment: The memory referenced by those pointers better also be shared or this is somewhat pointless.

Comment: Use offsets from the start of shared memory instead of pointers.

Comment: @Eddy_Em Thanks for your reply. I tried memcpy the structure contents to the shared memory, still the target process don't get it. Am I missing something very obvious?

Answer (score 5):

There is a note about this in the Linux man page for `shmat`:

```
       Using shmat() with shmaddr equal to NULL is the preferred, portable way
       of attaching a shared memory segment.  Be aware that the shared  memory
       segment  attached in this way may be attached at different addresses in
       different processes.  Therefore, any  pointers  maintained  within  the
       shared  memory must be made relative (typically to the starting address
       of the segment), rather than absolute.
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was using shm_open / mmap way of using shared memory for IPC. Ofcourse, I passed NULL to the 1st argument of mmap to let kernel decide where to place the memory segment.

Answer (score 3):

The struct contains two pointers, for `key` and `message`. They have values such as 0x1000 and 0x1040. Your first process maps shared memory, say at address 0x7000. It copies the struct into shared memory. The second process maps the same shared memory, say at address 0x9000. It reads the struct. Then it uses the pointers, which causes it to look for `key` and `message` at addresses 0x1000 and 0x1040. But they are not at those addresses in the memory of the second process. So the second process fails.

To fix this, you must arrange for `key` and `message` to be in shared memory, and you must either arrange for them to be at the same address in both processes (by telling `mmap` exactly where you want to map memory, not letting the system pick the address) or you must include information in the shared memory about how to locate `key` and `message`. This is often done by using offsets instead of pointers. That is, instead of having pointers to `char` in the struct, have offsets (possibly with type `ptrdiff_t`) that give the number of bytes from a base location to the key and the message. The beginning of the shared memory segment is a typical base to use.

If you have only one key and one message to shared, then a common way this is done is simply to use a single data structure for the shared memory, as you showed with your second definition of `shared_data`: The key and the message are part of the struct, so their offsets are known, simply as offsets from the beginning of the struct. If you are sharing more complicated data, such as trees or linked lists, then you may need to use explicit offsets.